# Cam someone explain what this statement does?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have troubles understanding the meaning of `(_,idx)` in the following statement

```
arr.filter((_, idx) => idx % 2 === 0)
```

I understand it is filtering the array and just returning on the new array all elements that respect the condition(basically with even index). But i do not understand what this (_,idx) means?

Any help?

Comment: The function has two parameters, `_` and `idx`.

Comment: [There is documentation you can read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: And since the first parameter does not actually get used in the callback function, but can’t be left out in the function arguments, someone probably decided to use `_` as parameter name here, to alert to that fact – “it’s a throwaway parameter.”

Comment: I'd suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(_, idx) are two variable names.

```
arr.filter((currentValue, index, array) => )
```

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

So "_" is currentValue and "idx" is the index.

"_" is not use but still defindes because it is a non-optional parameter, so you always have to give it an name.

Comment: Thank you. Now it makes sense.